# Compact operator without eigenvalues?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Consider the operator $M$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ defined by for $u\in \ell^2(\mathbb Z)$

$$Mu(n)=\frac{1}{\vert n \vert+1}u(n).$$ This is a compact operator!

Then, let $l$ be the left-shift and $r$ the right-shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z).$

We consider the compact operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z;\mathbb C^2)$ defined by

$$T:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & l M \\ rM & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

My question is: Even though $T$ is not normal, since $$T^*T= \begin{pmatrix} MlrM & 0 \\ 0 & Mr lM  \end{pmatrix}=M^2$$
whereas $$TT^*= \begin{pmatrix} lM^2 r & 0 \\ 0 & rM^2 l  \end{pmatrix}\neq M^2$$ does $T$ have eigenvalues?

Comment: What is $u$ in the definition of $M$? Where does $T$ act?

Comment: @FedorPetrov sorry, $u \in \ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ and $T$ acts on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z; \mathbb C^2).$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $$T^2 = \begin{pmatrix}lMrM&0\\0&rMlM\end{pmatrix},$$ and hence the eigenvectors of $T^2$ are $$v_j = (e_j, 0) , \qquad w_j = (0, e_j),$$ with corresponding eigenvalues $$\lambda_j = \frac{1}{(1 + |j|) (1 + |j+1|)} \, , \qquad \mu_j = \frac{1}{(1 + |j|) (1 + |j-1|)} \, ,$$ respectively. In particular, the eigenspaces of $T^2$ are four-dimensional: for $j \ge 0$, the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_j = \mu_{j+1} = \lambda_{-j-1} = \mu_{-j}$  is spanned by $v_j$, $u_{j+1}$, $v_{-j-1}$ and $u_{-j}$.

If $u$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then it is also an eigenvector of $T^2$, and hence it is a linear combination of $v_j$, $u_{j+1}$, $v_{-j-1}$ and $u_{-j}$ for some $j \ge 0$. By inspection, $$ T(a v_j + b u_{j+1} + c v_{-j-1} + d u_{-j}) = \frac{a u_{j+1} + d v_{-j-1}}{1 + |j|} + \frac{b v_j + c u_{-j}}{1 + |j + 1|} $$ corresponds to a simple block $4\times4$ matrix, and it is now an elementary exercise to find the eigenvectors.

Comment: interesting, do you see any argument using abstract arguments that there have to be eigenvalues? It seems in this case, the simple structure of the square bailed us out-which I missed. But perhaps it is clear already from something that there has to be at least one?

Comment: @Martinique: Of course there are compact operators with no eigenvalues whatsoever. On the other hand, if any power of $T$ is normal, then the above argument works (the cyclic subspace generated by an eigenvector $v$ of some $T^n$, that is, $\operatorname{lin}\{v, Tv, T^2v, T^3v,\ldots\}$ is finite-dimensional, and so $T$ has an eigenvector within this subspace).

Comment: There's a typo in the penultimate paragraph: 'If $u$ is an eigenvector of $T^2$, then it is also an eigenvector of $T^2$', while tautologically true, is certainly not what was meant there... :) I presume the first one is meant to be $T$ rather than $T^2$, since that implication is true and non-trivial...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Hardly non-trivial, I'd say, but yes, this is what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: Small remark: In case that one is only interested in the *existence* of eigenvalues (as the OP seems to be, according to their comments), one can replace the second half of the argument by just noting that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2$, than at least one of the complex roots of $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ (which is true for every linear operator $T$).

Comment: @JochenGlueck: That's true, thanks. (This is essentially what I was trying to write in one of the comments above).

Answer (score 4):

Sure, let $\mu_n = \frac{1}{|n|+ 1}$, then for each $n$ the vector $\sqrt{\mu_{n-1}}e_n\oplus \pm\sqrt{\mu_n}e_{n-1}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\pm\sqrt{\mu_n\mu_{n-1}}$.

Comment: Thank you also for your answer. Since Mateusz answered a few minutes earlier, I just accepted his answer, I hope this is okay. But let me also ask you, if you see any abstract argument that there have to be eigenvalues (so not by explicitly diagonalization) but by some a priori argument?

Comment: Well, under what assumptions? My construction works for your operator with any sequence in $c_0(\mathbb{Z})$ in place of $(\mu_n)$. In general every nonzero element of the spectrum of a compact operator is an eigenvalue, but there do exist compact operators with spectrum $\{0\}$ and no eigenvalues.